# Summation of a finite series involving permutations.

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

$$\large \sum_{i = 2}^{25}P(i,2)$$
$P$ stands for "permutations".

Comment: So do you know a formula for $P(i,2)$?  Do you know formulas for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$?

Comment: Yes,$$ P(i,2) = {i! \over (i -  2)!}$$
Second involves the sum of an arithmetic sequence.$${n(n + 1) \over 2}$$Third:$${n(n + 1)(2n + 1)\over 6} $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} P(i,2) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} \frac{i!}{(i-2)!} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} \frac{i (i-1) (i-2)!}{(i-2)!} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} i (i-1) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} (i^2 - i) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} i^2 - \displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{25} i$$

Comment: That was very good. Thanks, I can do the rest :)

Comment: There's a typo in the fourth and proceeding expressions: $\sum_{i=2}^{25}i(i-i)$.

Comment: The fourth summation says $$\sum_{i=2}^{25}i(i-i).$$

I take it that you meant $$\sum_{i=2}^{25}i(i-1).$$ Am I misunderstanding? If so, sorry.

Comment: @Limitless: You're right.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$i(i-1)=\frac{1}{3}\Big((i+1)(i)(i-1)-(i)(i-1)(i-2)\Big).$$
Add up from $i=2$ to $i=25$, and observe the beautiful cancellations (telescoping).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=2}^{25}P(i,2)=\sum_{i=2}^{25}\frac{i!}{(i-2)!}=\sum_{i=2}^{25}i(i-1)=\sum_{i=2}^{25}i^2-\sum_{i=2}^{25}i$$

There are well-known formulas for $\sum_{i=1}^ni$ and $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$ that you can use to finish the job; these formulas can be found (among many other places) in most standard calculus texts when summations are introduced preparatory to doing Riemann sums.